# Convert (decode) hexadecimal string to binary string

Tags: ruby

How can I convert `"1234567890"` to `"\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90"` in Ruby?

Comment: Judging by the answers, the output is supposed to be "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90", rather than an Array of Fixnum or a syntactically invalid Hash.

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
["1234567890"].pack('H*')
```

Comment: This is definitely the most elegant solution. The top voted answer will not do what is asked.

Answer (score 12):

Ruby 1.8 -

```
hex_string.to_a.pack('H*')
```

Ruby 1.9 / Ruby 1.8 -

```
Array(hex_string).pack('H*')
```

Comment: File.open('output.txt', 'w+') {|f| f.write(IO.read('input.txt').to_a.pack('H*')) }

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer is supposed to work. Could you give a better example using the hex string in the question? When I tried your code I got: `d:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> hex_string = "1234567890"
=> "1234567890"
irb(main):002:0> hex_string.to_a.pack('H*')
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for "1234567890":String
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>`

Comment: @ZombieDev, @steenslag Ruby 1.9 doesn't have `String#to_a` method. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a well-formed hexadecimal string (pairs of hex digits), you can pack to binary, or unpack to hex, simply & efficiently, like this:

```
string = '0123456789ABCDEF'
binary = [string].pack('H*')     # case-insensitive
 => "\x01#Eg\x89\xAB\xCD\xEF"
hex = binary.unpack('H*').first  # emits lowercase
 => "012345679abcdef"
```

Answer (score 4):

```rb
class String

  def hex2bin
    s = self
    raise "Not a valid hex string" unless(s =~ /^[\da-fA-F]+$/)
    s = '0' + s if((s.length & 1) != 0)
    s.scan(/../).map{ |b| b.to_i(16) }.pack('C*')
  end

  def bin2hex
    self.unpack('C*').map{ |b| "%02X" % b }.join('')
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you explain what the validation REGEX does?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string containing numbers and you want to scan each as a numeric hex byte, I think this is what you want:

```
"1234567890".scan(/\d\d/).map {|num| Integer("0x#{num}")}
```

Comment: I'd have done:  "1234567890".scan(/\d\d/).map {|i| i.to_i(16) }

Comment: Or, to handle **hex** characters as requested, `"1234567890abcdef".scan(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/).map { |i| i.to_i(16) }`.

Answer (score -1):

```rb
(0..4).map { |x| "0x%X" % (("1234567890".to_i(16) >> 8 * x) & 255) }.reverse
```