# Decode hexadecimal string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hex to binary in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862140/hex-to-binary-in-ruby)

In Python, I can do the following:

```
>>> str = '000E0000000000'
>>> str.decode('hex')
'\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

If I have to achieve the same output in ruby which call could I make? I tried `to_s(16)`, which doesn't seem to work. I need the output to be in that specific format, so I expect to get the following:

```
"\\x00\\x0e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00"
```

Comment: Perhaps this is the solution? 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84421/converting-an-integer-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-ruby][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84421/converting-an-integer-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-ruby

Comment: [str].pack('H*')
=> "\000\016\000\000\000\000\000"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
irb(main):002:0> [str].pack('H*')
# => "\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Or (Ruby 1.9 only):

```
irb(main):004:0> str.scan(/../).map(&:hex).map(&:chr).join
# => "\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

If you need the string formatted:

```
irb(main):005:0> s = str.scan(/../).map { |c| "\\x%02x" % c.hex }.join
=> "\\x00\\x0e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00"
irb(main):006:0> puts s
\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
=> nil
```

Comment: i get => "\000\016\000\000\000\000\000" for your solution I am running 1.8.7 ruby

Comment: @Pavan: Which is correct, seeing that `"\000\016" == "\x00\x0e"`

Comment: trouble is I need to get the \x00 format and not \000 format as the url receiver is complaining of invalid format whereas the python decode prints \x00 format and the url receiver doesn't complain for that

Comment: @Pavan: That's a formatting issue. What you want then is a string like `"\\x00\\x0e..."`. Lemme hack that up really quick.

Comment: @Pavan: Check my edit. Also, I edited your question to reflect your additional problem.